# Edit background in inactive days in DateTime Picker Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using DateTimePicker for the following project : https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php, I have two dates that I deactivate and I would like to put a red background on those dates.

Note : I use bootstrap 3

Code

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendario</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.es.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <form action="" class="form-horizontal"  role="form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dtp_input2" class="col-md-2 control-label">Date Picking</label>
                <div class="input-group date form_date col-md-5" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                    <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input2" value="" /><br/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var dates = ["11/11/2017","12/11/2017"];

  $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        language:  'es',
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        datesDisabled: dates
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.datetimepicker table tr td.disabled {
  background: red;
  color: black;
}

.datetimepicker table tr td.disabled:hover {
  background: red;
  color: black;
}
```

The problem is that it does not work, try modifying .datetimepicker by .datepicker but it does not work either

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably including your `style.css` before the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css`. As the selectors in your `style.css` are equally specific as the selectors in `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css` your rules are overwritten. Simply changing the order should solve your problem.